# Drupal 8 Bootstrap Theme Background "transparent" (e.g. offcanvas-lining visible)

Tags: theming, 8

I have installed the Drupal 8 Bootstrap Theme (version 8.x-3.0-rc2) on a newly setup site. When I logout and view the page everything looks as I would expect it. But while I am logged in when I click on "Back to Site" in the top left corner then I only see a background of`background-color: #333` which is being set by a class named `.offcanvas-lining`. This makes working with the theme almost impossible because the text and headers have the same color and so the text is invisible.

I could probably override that somehow but I would like to understand if this is an issue with the Drupal 8 theme or if I have made a mistake when I setup the theme.

What is this `offcanvas-lining` element doing and why am I seeing its background rather then the usual white bootstrap background which is the default.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this was being caused by the "Settings Tray" module which was added in Drupal 8 and which I had activated. Deactivating the module has fixed the issue for me.

It seems other people also have this issue with other themes: https://www.drupal.org/node/2819091